# Getting a constant DNS for my EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, dynamic-dns

I have an EC2 instance. Every time I stop and start it, Amazon gives it a new IP and a new DNS.

This is annoying because then I have to reconfigure a bunch of software on my local computer to interact with the new DNS.

Is there a way for me to have one DNS address that will always point to my instance?

Comment: Setup a DDNS name and configure your instance to update it a boot. There are quite a few DDNS providers and loads of help on configuring software to update it at boot time.

Comment: Have you contacted Amazon about this?

Comment: @Dan, if he contacts Amazon they'll tell him to buy an Elastic IP as James points out.

Comment: Buy? They're free, as long as you use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon's solution is called an "Elastic IP address" - a static external IP address that always points to your machine, regardless of its internal address.

There's some information on it on [the ec2 page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), and more information on how to configure it in [this walkthrough](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal) (which is aimed at solving a slightly different problem, but still mostly applicable here)

Comment: it's 2021 and ELastic IP are now limited to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the DDNS suggestion Chris S has ( such as http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html ), if you run your own DNS you can use Dynamic Updates ( IE Bind's http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#update-policy ) with TSIG/SIG

Answer (score 0):

As James Polley mentioned, Elastic IP adresses may be way to go in your case, I think.

Moreover, they're quite [inexpensive](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

> **Elastic IP Addresses**
>
> No cost for Elastic IP addresses while in use
>
> - $0.01 per non-attached Elastic IP address per complete hour
> - $0.00 per Elastic IP address remap – first 100 remaps / month
> - $0.10 per Elastic IP address remap – additional remap / month over 100